# My windows 7 install from upgrade media left a Windows.old folder

Tags: windows-7

I installed Win7 by starting install from Vista OS
and thought I would get the option to reformat C drive.

instead I have a Windows.old folder with all Vista files.

Is this ok or would it be best to reinstall from booting the install DVD?

I am a developer and will install alot of tools so I am wondering
what i shoudl do??

Malcolm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows.Old folder is there so that you have your old stuff (and I think it might even let you revert to Vista, but I'm not sure about that).

Since you wanted to reformat your disk, you probably got a backup.  Because you want to install a lot of tools, it would probably be best if you DO reformat your drive (after re-backing up whatever you've changed in the mean time).  To do this, you need to boot from the DVD.

Answer (score 1):

That's by design. And it will be there when you do a clean install, without formatting the disk. Pick the files you want out of there and then delete Windows.old.

Answer (score 1):

I have done 4 true upgrades from Vista to Windows 7.  None has a Windows.old folder.  My guess is that you choose the Custom? option to have a fresh installation of Windows 7, while preserving the Vista installation in the .old folder.

Another guess, if you want to reformat, boot from the new Windows 7 DVD.